# Best way to regularly download data from internet to iPhone app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have developed an iPhone application that fetches data from internet. I want to check every 30 seconds if there is new data. How do I do that in the best possible way?

The app contains data downloaded from a REST API. The data is light-weight JSON-strings with status updates that will be appended to a UITableView.

Comment: Can you please be more specific - eg, data type? Size? Possible actions?

Comment: Yes, some more info has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could poll using an NSTimer.